# Desktop icons on Kali are small

Tags: kali-linux, icons, appearance

I am using  Linux 6.0.0-kali3-amd64 on Oracle VirtualBox. But, to me the icons on the Desktop appear to be way too small. Same goes for the icons on the top ribbon. I looked up the internet but most of forums addressed the problem by increasing the scaling from 1x to 2x, which in my opinion gets too big. Is there another way around this? Any way to scale somewhere in between 1x and 2x?